# Commissions Saved Search

Tags: duplicates, netsuite, saved-searches

I am getting duplicate lines on my saved search when adding APPLYING LINK TYPE
APPLYING TRANSACTION. It then shows one invoice closed out by an invoice and credit when it should only show closed out by credit.  My saved search is a transaction search for invoices where Main line is true.